# how to use SendKeys method in vb script to select everything on page?

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to run a vbscript that will load up a html page in chrome and then do control+a which will select everything on the page, with the ultimate view to copy it and then paste it into excel.

this my script so far:

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Dim iURL 
Dim objShell

iURL = "C:\Users\Aasfasf\AppData\Local\Temp\TD_80\hpqc\52136023e30\****\121200.html"

set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.run(iURL)

WScript.Sleep 1500

WshShell.SendKeys "^a"
```

when I run it loads up the html page, but i dont think the control+a command is working as nothing is selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two suggestions:

1. The focus is probably not on the content in chrome.  Try sending a Tab key press a couple of times first to see if that fixes it.
2. A better approach to this might be to just read the contents of the file, then delete all the markup from the document using regex.

Answer (score 0):

Excel can just load your web page without needing any help from you.

**Alt + D, D, W**